# How to query with two database (one remotely) in codeigniter 3?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm trying to query two tables from two databases using codeigniter db active records.

I have two database in which one i'm remotely connecting like given in this [page](https://techalltype.com/mysql-remote-access-how-to-connect-mysql-database-remotely-using-codeigniter/).

My code goes like this:-

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $db2 = $this->load->database('nc', TRUE); // remote database connection

        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from($db2->database . '.posts a');
        $this->db->join('authors b', 'a.pid = b.aid', 'left');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $rows = [];
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $rows = $query->result();
        }

        echo "<pre>"; print_r ($rows); echo "</pre>";exit;

    }

}
```

**I'm keep getting the error remotedatabase.posts doesn't exist.**

But when i query like below, i'm getting the results but the issue is i'm not able to do join etc.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Posts extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $db2 = $this->load->database('nc', TRUE); // remote database connection

        $res = $db2->query(' SELECT * FROM posts ');
        $rows = [];
        if ($res->num_rows() > 0) {
            $rows = $res->result();
        }

        echo "<pre>"; print_r ($rows); echo "</pre>";exit;

    }

}
```

Comment: remove the . from '.posts a'

Comment: You don't need to use database name (and most likely it's not named `remotedatabase`), just use `$this->db->from('posts a')`

Comment: @Justinas remotedatabase is the name of the database which i'm connecting remotely.

Comment: @Justinas now it's says posts table doesn't exist in db1. Assume that db2 is the remotely connected db name.